# "LIKE" operator does not work on agensgraph

Tags: agens-graph

I want to find a name using `LIKE` operator.

There is no `LIKE` operator on AgensGraph.

```
santino=# match (n:v) where n.name like 'j%' return n.name;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "like"
LINE 1: match (n:v) where n.name like 'j%' return n.name;
```

Is there another way to find a specific pattern of strings?

Answer (score 0):

First, CYPHER is distinct from SQL.
CYPHER does not support "LIKE" operator.
But, you can use alternative operators that CYPHER supports.

See the examples:

```
agens=# MATCH (n:v) WHERE n.name STARTS WITH 'j' RETURN n.name;
 name  
-------
 "joe"
(1 row)

agens=# MATCH (n:v) WHERE n.name ENDS WITH 'e' RETURN n.name;
 name  
-------
 "joe"
(1 row)

agens=# MATCH (n:v) WHERE n.name CONTAINS 'o' RETURN n.name;
 name  
-------
 "joe"
(1 row)
```

Good lock.